# python read data build association rules

Tags: python, associations, rules

I have two columns in a text file. I read them into Python into two separate lists. What I want to do is count the occurences of each pair and build association rules based on it.

Example:

```
colA = [a,b,c,d,...]

colB = [c,y,d,e,...]
```

I came only so far to read the data into the two lists but what is the best way to count the occurences and build the rules?

Code:

```
pred = []
succ = []
for line in open('arsample.txt'):
    lst = line.split('\t')
    pred.append(int(lst[0]))
    succ.append(int(lst[1]))
```

Rules would look like this and are sorted descending:

```
P   S   Probability
---------------------
a > c   count(a>c)/n
...     ...
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do. With the sample data you gave, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on *sets :*

```
 http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html
```

They allow this :

```
>>> a = [1,2,2,5,4,5,4,2,1,3]
>>> set(a)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>>
```

So you will have to build the pairs in a list of strings, I guess...

Hope it can help.

Comment: Looks good but I still need the count of the pairs otherwise I cannot calculate the probability.

Comment: Then you'd probably better with the itertools  :   from itertools import groupby   :  will give you the sets and the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dictionary` to create a mapping:

```
mapping = {}

for key in colA:
  mapping[key] = colB.index(key)
```

To count the occurrences, just use `.count()`:

```
colA.count('a')
```

Note that the mapping will break if `colB` has two elements with the same name. This is because you're trying to build a bijection between two non-unique sets, which won't work. Think of it like recovering the input number from `x^2`. You just don't know.

Comment: colB has elements with the same name so this is a problem.

Comment: You can't construct a mapping.